# How to change the language of the Excel Calendar Control

Tags: vba, excel, calendar

Using MS Excel 2003, I'd like to change the language of a Calendar Control I inserted. I'd like to get the names of months and weekdays in English, and not in Spanish (the local language of my PC).

I don't know how to do it. I've been searching in Google, with no success.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the language of the calendar control probably depends on the language version of the dll or, more likely, the default locale for either the system or the user. But i cannot find a definitive reference to that, either.

But there is at least [an article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760913(v=vs.85).aspx#localization) related to the Windows UI Month Calendar Control that supports my guessing.